# jQuery Mobile dynamic page back navigation

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an app with the following flow:

page1 -> page2-> *clicks on button-> video(player.vimeo)

The problem is that my app gets dynamic content and I want to return to page2 after viewing the video but when I get back to the page(by clicking back button of android phones) the content is lost.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Put the whole process (code) of dynamically crating the page, navigation etc in your question. how is anyone going to know whats happening exactly.

Comment: So I tried using html5box to remain on that page and open the video from there, with the following code:

<a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/101507206" class="html5lightbox" data-width="480" data-height="320" id="movVid">Video</a>

This works ok if its hard-coded, but if I get dynamic value of href using this code:

var trailer_link = movies_res.get("Trailer_Link");
  $("#movVid").attr('href',trailer_link);
  $("#movVid").show();

This shows opens the video in the window instead of the lightbox.